# Add Double Quotes Around Output Field

Tags: linux, awk

I'm trying to surround `awk` output fields with double quotes but, keep running into errors. This code is running in a bash script on an Ubuntu system

**Errors**

```
awk: cmd. line:1: BEGIN {print "<table id="\"alert\"",">"} ; {  print "<tr><td class="\"site\"",">" $1 "</td><td class="\"fdate\"",">" $2 "</td><td class="\"prcp\"",">" $3 "</td><td class="\"snow\"",">" $4 "</td><td class="\"tmp2m\"",">" $5 "</td><td class="\"dpt2m\"",">" $6 "</td><td class="\"wchill\"",">" $7 "</td><td class="\"wind10m\"",">" $8 "</td></tr>"} ; END { print "</table>"}
awk: cmd. line:1:                          ^ backslash not last character on line
awk: cmd. line:1: BEGIN {print "<table id="\"alert\"",">"} ; {  print "<tr><td class="\"site\"",">" $1 "</td><td class="\"fdate\"",">" $2 "</td><td class="\"prcp\"",">" $3 "</td><td class="\"snow\"",">" $4 "</td><td class="\"tmp2m\"",">" $5 "</td><td class="\"dpt2m\"",">" $6 "</td><td class="\"wchill\"",">" $7 "</td><td class="\"wind10m\"",">" $8 "</td></tr>"} ; END { print "</table>"}
awk: cmd. line:1:                          ^ syntax error
```

**Attempted Code**

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN {print "<table id="\"alert\"",">"} ; {  print "<tr><td class="\"site\"",">" $1 "</td><td class="\"fdate\"",">" $2 "</td><td class="\"prcp\"",">" $3 "</td><td class="\"snow\"",">" $4 "</td><td class="\"tmp2m\"",">" $5 "</td><td class="\"dpt2m\"",">" $6 "</td><td class="\"wchill\"",">" $7 "</td><td class="\"wind10m\"",">" $8 "</td></tr>"} ; END { print "</table>"}' /home/weather/csv > /home/weather/csv.html
```

Comment: suggest to add sample input/output for clarity and testing... also, you could use html parsers/modules...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got too many quotes going on, and you probably don't want to separate the individual items to be printed with commas:

```
$ awk -F, 'BEGIN {print "<table id=\"alert\"" ">"}'
<table id="alert">
```

Sometimes it helps to set the double quote as a variable to make things more readable:

```
$ awk -F, -v q='"' 'BEGIN {print "<table id=" q "alert" q ">"}'
<table id="alert">
```

Comment: This is great, thank you! I'm using this code to convert a CSV file to HTML code so, I need each of the eight variables to be printed

Comment: Yes, I understand. Following this pattern should get you there, but if you're still having errors with the full awk, come back with another comment.

Comment: FINAL CODE: `awk -F, 'BEGIN {print "<table id=\"alert\"" ">"} ; {print "<tr><td class=\"site\"" ">" $1 "</td><td class=\"fdate\"" ">" $2  "</td><td class=\"prcp\"" ">" $3 "</td><td class=\"snow\"" ">" $4 "</td><td class=\"tmp2m\"" ">" $5 "</td><td class=\"dpt2m\"" ">" $6 "</td><td class=\"wchill\"" ">" $7 "</td><td class=\"wind10m\"" ">" $8 "</td></tr>"} ; END { print "</table>"}' /home/weather/csv > /home/weather/csv.html`

Comment: @ampry take a second to think about what you're doing as you seem to be just throwing as many quotes as possible at the problem. For example you have `"</td><td class=\"site\"" ">"` when all you need is `"</td><td class=\"site\">"` and in reality you should just be using printfs like `printf "<td class=\"site\">%s</td>", $1` instead of `print "<tr><td class=\"site\"" ">" $1 "</td>"` and there's even simpler ways to do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you should really be approaching this (untested):

```
awk -F, '
BEGIN {
    split("site,fdate,prcp,snow,tmp2m,dpt2m,wchill,wind10m",tags)
    print "<table id=\"alert\">"
}
{
    printf "<tr>"
    for (i=1; i in tags; i++) {
        printf "<td class=\"%s\">%s</td>", tags[i], $i
    }
    print "</tr>"
}
END { print "</table>"}
' /home/weather/csv
```